# Cloud Function throwing error Type Error for bigquery client, but working fine on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, api, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create a Cloud Function that fetches data from bigquery. The code is working fine on Jupyter but doesn't work on Cloud Function.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

def main(request):
    os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] ='xxxx.json'
    bigquery_client = bigquery.Client(project='xxxx')

    query = """select scavenger_hunt_mode_time_spent_minutes, explore_mode_time_spent_minutes,
           browsemode_time_spent_minutes, nationalpark_time_spend_minutes, explore_marker_tracked_ids,
           browsemode_content_clicked_models_ids,browsemode_content_clicked_maps, national_park_lifetime_scenarios_solved,
           scavenger_hunt_mode_session_story_ids_completed, time from `plugo-244108.mix.new_tableau_orboot*` where Email='xxx.com' and orbootername='xxxx'"""
    query_job = bigquery_client.query(query)
    geography = query_job.to_dataframe()

    return len(geography)
```

`TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a int.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud function follows the syntax of Flask - https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-python, hence doesn't work when `int` gets returned in the view. A simple change of `return len(geography)` to `return str(len(geography))` should make the function work.

Just an add on, `len(geography.index)` should be faster than `len(geography)`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Also, AWS Lambda plus API Gateway worked like a charm in this situation.